# Retrive data using PHP and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here I am trying to fetch data from `Mysql` database using `PHP` and `Ajax`. My problem is, when I type the `Test ID` on `test_id` `text box`, just it immediatetly shows the `Test Name` according to the `Test ID` on `test_name` `text box`.

Here I used the `function` called `checkname`. In console just it show the `Test Name` but does not show in the `test_name` `text box`.

Here is the `HTML` code.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-white">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col-sm-1">Test ID</th>
    <th class="col-md-6">Test Name</th>
    <th style="width:100px;">Amount</th>
    <th> Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="rows">
   <tr>
     <td> <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width:200px" id="test_id[]" onblur="checkname();" onkeyup="checkname();" onchange="checkname();"> </td>
     <td> <input  type="text" style="width:300px" class="form-control text-right form-amt"  readonly="" id="test_name[]" > </td>
     <td> <input  type="text" style="min-width:100px" class="form-control text-right form-amt" readonly="" id="amount[]"> </td>
     <td><center> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-success font-18" title="Add" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> </center> </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the `Ajax` code;

```
<script>

function checkname()
{
var test_id = document.getElementById("test_id[]").value;
$.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: "adminquery/fetch_test_name.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
       data: {'test_id': test_id, },
       success: function (data) {
           $("#test_name[]").html(data);
         }
        });
           }
</script>
```

Here is the `PHP` code

```
<?php
include('../auth/dbconnection.php');
$output='';
$sql="SELECT * from testings where test_id='".$_POST['test_id']."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$name= $row["testing_name"];
  $output.='    <input  type="text"  readonly="" id="test_name[]" value="'.$name.' "> '.$name.'   ';
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Anyone could help me may highly appreciated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard: sure, i will try it

Comment: `id=test_name[]` the brackets are just not necessary. ID's do not act like names in HTML, they must be unique. Additionally, open the browsers' developer tools and make sure you're sending to the PHP what you expect to send.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, here i am trying to add dynamic buttons by clicking the button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First lose the brackets in the id.

```
<input id="test_name" type="text" value="other" />
```

Then use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

```
$("#test_name").val("something")
```